# Offline Map in Sencha Touch

Tags: sencha-touch

How to work Offline Map in Sencha Touch. Any Example for Offline Map with marker using Sencha Touch without using Phonegap Example. Is it have any lib files?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into this myself...you have 2 options, GeoExt and Ext.ux.leaflet.

Have a look in the sencha touch 1x examples forum, there is a post there about Leaflet.

To download the tiles the developer supplied a python script to download the tiles. My alternative method was to pan around the whole map at the initial zoom level, zoom in one level and pan around the whole map and repeat until you are happy with the levels of zoom you want. In safari's activity monitor you can see all the .png tiles downloading. Then save as a safari web archive. Use the safari web archive extractor you can find on google (mac only) and it will keep the folder intact with all the downloaded tiles. You can then reference these files locally by changing the link in the .js file.
Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

After revisiting this, I finally found a solution. You can download .mbtiles maps and unarchive them with mbutil. The you can reference the unarchived folder in the path in your Leaflet app....by changing the URL to http:// localhost

You may also be able to use Tilemill to generate a custom map that you can then export and reference in Leaflet.

Download the leaflet extension on GitHub (there are 2, one works better than the other) and try first by changing the leaflet URL with an online map link from mapbox (you can find the URL when you click 'share' on a map)

;-)